# Facebook Graph api unable to delete or hide comments on my facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Graph api unable to delete or hide any comments on my facebook wall , i tested it on graph api explorer with my user access token all permission choosed.

Api Explorer gives Error code;

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Users can only delete their own comments published by the same app",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "ETKJyLTeU9x"
  }
}
```

if i try to hide i get this error;

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#210) Updating is_hidden requires a Page access token",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 210,
    "fbtrace_id": "BZMXQFBHo9k"
  }
}
```

but actually this comment is not on page wall its my own user wall.

Comment: Pretty obvious from the error messages that it is not possible

Comment: yeah, we could just copy and paste the error messages as answer ;)

Comment: i opened a ticket to facebook for this situation and waiting for response :)

Comment: Hi Osman, can you link to that issue here as well, please? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=885279158245770&added&rdrhc

Answer (score 0):

check the can_hide field of the comment. If it is "can_hide": false, you are not allowed to hide.

Comment: it is OK but always can_hide : false for personal walls :)